# cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed in ios

Tags: ios

I sync from git hub desktop development branch then I open abc.xcodeprof file I can not open error message

> "abc.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be
>   parsed."

I also tried create whole new reposaroty in git hub desktop. is there any solution you know that can open my abc.xcodeproj file please give me.

This error message

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The most common cause turned out to be, that the "conflict text" from a git merge is crept into the actual file:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
                some code
=======
                some code
>>>>>>>
```

You can check it by opening the project file in a text editor and then fix it.
opening the project.pbxproj in a text editor made the fix easy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Although I **am** using git, already checked this one and search for "<<<<" gives zero results. Any other candidate...?

Comment: It worked for me but this time I can't open my Main.Storyboard file. The error says "Interface builder was unable to determine the type of Main.Storyboard. This may be due to a missing SDK

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue. Fixed all cases of

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
            some code
=======
            some code
>>>>>>>
```

But the issue was one of those markers was going through a }; that finished a block in my .pbxproj file. Going through and making sure all brackets are closed might be the answer.